# show the sum of the digits of any multiple of $10^k-1$ is at least $9k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

> Show that for any positive integer k, the sum of the digits of any multiple of $10^k-1$ is at least $9k$.

It is clearly sufficient to deal with nonnegative multiples, since if $S(x)$ is the sum of digits of the integer x, then $S(x)=S(-x)$ for any integer x. The claim holds for $k=1$ because all positive multiple of $9$ have sum of digits equal to a positive multiple of $9$, and hence the sum of the digits is at least $9$.  We know that $S(x+y) \leq S(x)+S(y)$ for all nonnegative integers x and y. Also, $S(x)\leq x$ for all nonnegative x with equality iff $0\leq x\leq 9$.

I'm not sure if the sum of the digits of any multiple of $10^k-1$ is always a multiple of $9k$.

We need to show that $S(a(10^k-1)) \equiv 0\mod 9k$ for all $k\ge 1, a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let N be a positive integer with $N>10^k.$ I think we can show there is some integer $M<N$ congruent to $N$ modulo $10^k-1$ with $S(M)\leq S(N)$. Then from this result, we can solve the question by induction; $S(10^k-1) = 9k$ and if for some multiple $N > 10^k-1,$ we assume that $S(M) \ge 9k$ for all multiples smaller than $N$, then the given claim shows that there is a multiple $M < N$ of $10^k-1$ so that $S(M)\leq S(N)$, from which the result follows. Write $N = q(10^k-1) + r$ where $r < 10^k - 1$. Suppose for a contradiction that  there is some $N > 10^k$ so that for all $M < N$ with $M \equiv N\mod 10^k-1$, we have $S(M) > S(N).$ The sum of the digits of a nonnegative integer is equivalent to its remainder modulo 9. There might be a useful formula involving the sum of digits of the sum of two numbers and the number of carries when addition is done between them.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24S(n(10%5E%7Bk%7D-1))%5Cge%209%5E%7Bk%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1), I found the AoPS thread's [Post #$4$ of IMO ShortList $1999$, number theory problem $6$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19768p2052194) solves your problem fully. There's also many posts which solve a more restricted version, specifically that for multiples up to $10^k$ times, the sum of the digits is exactly $9k$, e.g., [Prove that $s(N(10^{n}-1)) = s(10^{n}-1)$](/q/2213480) here, as well as many AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Important lemma](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1422221p7995952), [From a problem in Hong Kong TST 1994](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1582535p9773431), [Albania BMO TST Problem 2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1415068p7971818), [Sum of digits for 99..9](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1762477p11526393), [sum of digit, multiple 10^t-1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1433575p8102862), [Sum of digits](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1547906p9397190), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is the least positive multiple of $10^k-1$ which achieves the minimum digit sum.

We claim that this forces $N \le 10^k-1$; if this were not true, we could write $N = A\cdot 10^k + B$ with $B < 10^k$ ($B$ holds the last $k$ digits of $N$ and $A$ holds the rest).  Then $A+B$ would also be a positive multiple of $10^k-1$, which is strictly smaller than $N$ (since $N \ge 10^k$), and $S(A+B) \le S(A) + S(B) = S(N)$, contradicting the assumption that $N$ is the smallest specimen with minimum digit sum.

Thus, $N$ has at most $k$ digits, and being a positive multiple of $10^k-1$ must be exactly $10^k-1$, which has $S(N) = 9k$.

Answer (score -4):

For k>0,You need to show1) 10^k-1 has only 9s as digits and 2)has length k always.
1)prove by induction: case k=1, 10^k-1=9=(9)1.
For k>1,
10^k-1=9*(1+…+10^(k-1))=9…9(think:decimal expansion of a length k number whose digits are all 9s)
2) the last part of the proof of 1) is the proof of 2)
QED.
Thank you

Comment: That shows that the sum of digits of $10^k-1$ is $9k$.  OP asked about any multiple of this number, not just the number itself.

Comment: Oh… that’s a little harder